# Booting of Win 10 not possible, how to fix UEFI and/or bcdedit bootmgr?

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, bcdedit, bootmgr

### Problem

During the boot of my Win-10-Pro-system I get a BSOD `Kmode_Exception_Not_Handled` without further information provided. This results in a reboot. The error occurred after I had tried to edit UEFI-boot-entries and -order with bcdedit.

Before the error occurred I mistakenly entered the following in Windows-cmd-shell:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displayorder {<GUID>} /addfirst
```

where `<GUID>` was the Debian-entry of `{fwbootmgr}`. I actually wanted to change `{fwbootmgr}` and not `{bootmgr}`. My intended command was

```
bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} displayorder {<GUID>} /addfirst
```

Since I accidently mixed values for`{fwbootmgr}` and `{bootmgr}` the Windows-Bootmanager has values it cannot handle.

What makes things worse: The partition is Bitlocker-encrypted and there is no WinRE-partition.

### Background

I have a dual-boot with Debian Bookworm. The system did not automatically load Grub which is my general bootloader. Instead I had to manually boot from EFI-Shell. I wanted to set this right again when the error occured.

### What I tried

I made a Win-Install-USB-Stick with Media Creation Toolkit and wanted to repair my Win-installation with it. Strangely I also get a “Kmode_Exception_Not_Handled” during boot from stick followed by a reboot. I am still able to boot into Debian manually through EFI-Shell, though.

### Questions

How can I fix UEFI so that I can at least boot from stick?

When UEFI is fixed so that I can boot a Windows again then how can I delete the wrong value and change to the old display order in {bootmgr}? Is it possible to do that through a Windows-repair from stick?

**Any help appreciated.**

Comment: Try a Windows 10 Startup Repair form the Windows 10 ISO.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/windows-boot-issues-troubleshooting   Method 1 startup repair

Comment: The best fix is to restore from the last disk image.

Comment: @OP do you have a full backup of the entire disk?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by myself: The key to the solution was to boot into Linux and delete "Microsoft"-folder on the EFI-partition (/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft from Linux). Then you can use a Windows installation media to boot into command line and recreate it using the command "bcdboot". Booting into Linux and reinstalling grub will bring back the state of the system before the error occured.